# Comparing keys and values in python dictionaries

Tags: python, database, dictionary

say I have two dictionaries d1 and d2 looking like this:

```
d1={569328: inf,
 574660: inf,
 1187498: 1,
 1226468: 2,
 1236571: inf,
 1239098: 1,
 1239277: 5,
 1239483: inf,
 1239622: 9,
 1239624: inf,
 1239749: inf,
 1334477: 6,
 1340405: inf,
 1340418: inf,
 1340462: 2,
 1340471: inf}
```

```
d2={596005: [569328],
 4321416: [1334477, 1187498],
 5802640: [569328, 1226468],
 6031690: [569328,
  1340462,
  1239622,
  1187498,
  1239277]}
```

What I would like to do is to substitute the items of d2 with the numbers in d1 whenever the item of d2 coincides with the key of d1. In other words I would like to obtain the following at the end:

```
d3={596005: [inf],
 4321416: [6, 1],
 5802640: [inf, 2],
 6031690: [inf,
  2,
  9,
  1,
  5]}
```

Please, be aware that my original dictionaries are much longer, hence solutions being not complex are preferred (I mean linear complexity would be great :))

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to write anything up yet? Are the values in d2 always lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the get method and some isinstance checks to protect against missing keys in those d2 lists and protect against getting something other than a list.

This will skip anything that's not a list. And it will use `math.nan` for cases when the numbers in the d2 lists don't match up any of the keys in d1, which I'm guessing can easily happen.

```
import math

d1={569328: math.inf,
    574660: math.inf,
    1187498: 1,
    1226468: 2,
    1236571: math.inf,
    1239098: 1,
    1239277: 5,
    1239483: math.inf,
    1239622: 9,
    1239624: math.inf,
    1239749: math.inf,
    1334477: 6,
    1340405: math.inf,
    1340418: math.inf,
    1340462: 2,
    1340471: math.inf}

d2={596005: [569328],
    4321416: [1334477, 1187498],
    5802640: [569328, 1226468],
    6031690: [569328, 1340462, 1239622, 1187498, 1239277]}

missing_default = math.nan
for key, val_list in d2.items():
    if isinstance(val_list, list):
        for i in range(0, len(val_list)):
            new_num = d1.get(val_list[i], missing_default)
            val_list[i] = new_num
            d2[key] = val_list
```

`print(d2)` results in:
`{596005: [inf], 4321416: [6, 1], 5802640: [inf, 2], 6031690: [inf, 2, 9, 1, 5]}`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from math import inf

d3 = {k: [d1[v] for v in lst] for k, lst in d2.items()}
print(d3)
```

Prints:

```
{596005: [inf], 4321416: [6, 1], 5802640: [inf, 2], 6031690: [inf, 2, 9, 1, 5]}
```

---

If you want to modify `d2`:

```
for lst in d2.values():
    lst[:] = (d1[v] for v in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
d3 = {}
for k in d2:
    d3[k] = [d1[i] for i in d2[k]]
```